# YAML in R: Passing in a one element list

Tags: r, yaml

```
library(yaml)    

qq <- list(
      n = list(c('foo',''), c('bar','bar')), 
      m = list(c('foo',''))
    ); 
identical(yaml.load(as.yaml(qq)), qq);
```

FALSE

```
qq <- list(
  n = list(c('foo',''), c('bar','bar')), 
  m = list(c('foo',''), c('bar', 'bar')
); 

identical(yaml.load(as.yaml(qq)), qq);
```

TRUE

I'm trying to pass in a yaml file where m should be a list of length 1.

Unsure why this doesn't work when m is a list of length 1, but works exactly as expected with length = 2?

yaml_2.1.11

Help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it looks like you might be able to work around this issue by simply having names for the list elements.

```
library(yaml)

test <- within(test <- list(), {
  len1            <- list('foo')
  len2            <- list('foo', 'bar')
  len1.named      <- list(n = 'foo')
  len2.named      <- list(n = 'foo', m = 'bar')
  len1.nest       <- list(list('foo'))
  len2.nest       <- list(list('foo', 'bar'))
  len1.nest.named <- list(list(n = 'foo'))
  len2.nest.named <- list(list(n = 'foo', m = 'bar'))
  qq              <- list(n = list(c('foo',''), c('bar','bar')), 
                          m = list(c('foo',''))) 
  qq.named        <- list(n = list(c('foo',''), c('bar','bar')), 
                          m = list(x = c('foo',''))) 
})

lapply(test, function(x) identical(x, yaml.load(as.yaml(x))))
# $len1
# [1] FALSE
# 
# $len2
# [1] FALSE
# 
# $len1.named
# [1] TRUE
# 
# $len2.named
# [1] TRUE
# 
# $len1.nest
# [1] FALSE
# 
# $len2.nest
# [1] FALSE
# 
# $len1.nest.named
# [1] TRUE
# 
# $len2.nest.named
# [1] TRUE
# 
# $qq
# [1] FALSE
# 
# $qq.named
# [1] TRUE
```